# Запись текущей даты в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть необходимость создавать файл с именем-Текущая дата и писать текущую дату в файл. Для записи в файл использую

```
data_log = datetime.date.today()
print(data_log)

f = open('Log.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')
f.write(data_log + '\n') вот тут ошибка. Как исправить? И дату в имя?
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно преобразовать объект даты в строку:

```
f.write(str(data_log) + '\n')
```

или

```
f.write(data_log.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') + '\n')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Совсем голова с утра не варит)